# Voice Control iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, voice, voice-control

I would like to build a simple reader app for the iPad 2 that would allow users to navigate/read via voice controls. The app would allow the user to enter a mode where the microphone was live and listened for predefined keywords like 'down', 'up', 'next', 'back', 'home', etc. 
I don't want to reinvent the wheel on this so I'm just wondering first, if someone has done this already and if not, are there any good tutorials or SDKs available to help with recording someone's voice, and then comparing future output to see if it matches, or just dealing with the microphone in general?

Answer (score 0):

Let's put aside that this is a fairly vaguely worded question for the moment.

If you are expecting to allow voice control in your app that somehow works throughout the entire device, it's just not possible. Your app would only work to control itself -- or at least itself and whatever external hooks you can normally get to the rest of the device, like, say, playing a song out of the user's iTunes library.

If you're planning on doing this in a jailbroken environment, then you should find some open-source library that does voice recognition -- if there are any -- and start from there. Be prepared for a very long haul, though.

Comment: Sorry, for the poorly worded question. Let me try again. I'm wanting to build a simple reading app, that would allow users to read some text (not important how it gets in there, say RSS for example), that would scroll down the page when they say the word 'down'. I would just be looking for help on how to do this. It would only be in the app, I'm not thinking at all about system wide. Is that any better?

Comment: @MarcTanis You don't want to develop a voice recognition library on your own unless you want a word of hurt. Try searching with Google for "voice recognition library ios"

Answer (score 0):

Dragon Mobile SDK is what you're looking for.
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/

There maybe others voice recognition SDKs out there, but this is the only one I can think of from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a library called CMU Sphinx. There's an iphone version for it called 
[PocketSphinx](http://www.rajeevan.co.uk/pocketsphinx_in_iphone/). See if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to build a simple reader app for the iPad 2 that would allow users to navigate/read via voice controls.

The iOS 13 new feature **Voice Control** fully meets your request because you can control your device and your app with your voice exactly the same as with touches.

It's also possible to define actions for some specific words for instance.

The device settings are perfectly well detailed to handle this amazing new feature *(`Accessibility` - `Voice Control`)*:
[image]

If you need dedicated names to be read out in your app, use the **`accessibilityUserInputLabels`** property to define them.

That's definitely the built-in tool your need to reach your goal: no need to use external library or SDK, everything is natively provided.  ;o)